# Difference between "done with me" and "done to me"

Tags: prepositions

Could somebody tell me what is the main difference between these two:

> What have you done *with* me?

or

> what have you done *to* me?

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to answer with slightly different examples: the difference between

> What have you done WITH my bicycle?
>   What have you done TO my bicycle?

Suppose someone borrowed my bicycle.

I might ask the first question if they came back without the bicycle. What have you done **with** it?

The second could be asked if they brought it back with a bent wheel. What have you done **to** it?

Returning to the actual question, asking

> What have you done WITH me?

does not really make any sense, but if someone has spread false rumours about me, ruining my reputation, and so I lost my job, I might ask

> What have you done TO me?

Comment: [NIKÍTA. Mother, mother! It seems my time has come! What have you done with me? How the little bones crunched, and how it whimpered! My own mother! What have you done with me?](http://great-authors.albertarose.org/leo_tolstoy/power_of_darkness/Act4.htm) Translated by Arthur Hopkins **circa 1919**

Comment: @MvLog maybe, but for an English Language learner who has to ask the question about prepositions it's a bit OT. I could think of another way it could be said but didn't think it was helpful.